# Round robin algorithm in operating system

Tags: operating-system

I just wanted to make sure that what I am doing is right.

I am working for my midterm and I got old midterms from my friend, there is one question in  regarding Round Robin secluding algorithm. It has following information. Time slice is 2.

```
Job No       Arrival Time      CPU Time

1             0                 8

2             4                 4

3             5                 3

4             6                 1

5            7                  5
```

I am asked to draw Gantt chart from above information.

(I am not sure how I can show it here, but bellow is one try. I am not good at formating tools)

Job  1 || 1  || 2  ||  3 || 4  ||  5 ||   1  ||   2  ||   3 ||  5   ||  1  ||  5  ||

Time   0-2| 2-4 | 4-6 |  6-8 | 8-9 | 9-11 | 11-13 | 13-15 | 15-16| 16-18 | 18-20| 20-21

You can read like below (Sorry for inconvenience)

Job 1 starts at 0 and ends at 2 at first interval and then it continues till 4, later job 2 starts at 4 and ends at 6. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: The answer is yes. Not sure what the question is though...

Comment: @Cosmin-I want to draw Gantt chart of above table.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
1 XXXX_______XX_____XX.
2 ....XX_______XX......
3 ....._XX_______X.....
4 ......__X............
5 .......__XX_____XX__X

X = Active
_ = Queued
```

I think that's the basic form of a Gantt chart. Just show what each job is up to throughout the time period.

Comment: @Jeffrey- I guess I am looking something like this link.http://www.cs.ucla.edu/~kohler/class/05s-osp/notes/notes5.html

Comment: @cool - Or, perhaps you are looking something like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart